# Proof Invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an invertible matrix $A$, such that $A^{-1}=A^T$. Prove that $\det(A^2)=1$.
I am not able to start and find a matrix such that $A^{-1}=A^T$.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some properties that should help you prove the result:

1. $\det(AB) = \det(A) \cdot \det(B)$.
2. $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$.

To construct such a matrix, look at a matrix whose columns are orthonormal. These matrices are called [unitary matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix).

Comment: @VedranŠego $A^* = A^T$, when the matrices are real.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix such that $A^{-1} = A^T$ is called an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), the simplest example of which is the identity matrix.

As a hint towards proving the claim, note that

$$\det(A^2) = \det(A) \cdot \det(A) = \det(A) \cdot \det(A^T)$$